# If $\int_{0}^{4} f(x) \text{dx} = 17, \text{ what is } \int_{1}^{5} f(x-1) \text{dx}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I tried manipulating the integral into a sum of integrals, but that isn't taking me anywhere:

$\int_{1}^{5} f(x-1) \text{ dx} = \int_{0}^{1} f(x-1) \text{ dx} + \int_{1}^{4} f(x-1) \text{ dx} + \int_{4}^{5} f(x-1) \text{ dx}$

*First of all, I don't even know how to establish a relationship between $\int f(x) \text{dx}$ and $\int f(x-1) \text{dx}$.*

Comment: They are the same. The answer is 17

Comment: By translation rules, $f(x-1)$ is simply $f(x)$ shifted one unit to the right. The bounds of integration have also been shifted one unit to the right, so both definite integrals are equivalent.

Comment: Try substitution, $y=x-1$ and see how the bounds are changing.

Comment: The first thing you need to do when you have this kind of questions is to find an example. This will give you the answer (quit easy right?) then you just have to figure out why it is true (i.e. give a proof) but this is much easier once you know what you should get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t = x-1$ , $dx =dt$

At $x =1 \ ,\  t = 0$

At $x =5 \ , \ t =4$

So $I = \int^5_1 f(x-1)dx = \int^4_0f(t)dt = 17$  (variable doesn't matter in definite integral)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome..

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate the second expression by the substitution $y = x - 1$ you will see that it becomes the first integral. Hence both integrals have the same value.